# Sprinkler valve not turning on by automatic timer

Tags: sprinkler-system, timer

I just programmed my sprinkler settings for Spring. I have back and front zones. 1-5 in the back, 6-8 in the front.

I noticed that station 6 is not turning on by the timer. It reads Err.

Here's what I've tried:

- Station 6 turns on manually at the valve without the timer
- At the timer, I took the 6 wire and doubled up on the 1 station. Timer read Err.
- At the valves, I connected the 6 wire to the 7 wire/valve. I ran 7, and timer read Err.

Seems like any time station 6 is involved, the timer will read Err.

What kind of problem does this point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done good testing. Almost certainly the electric solenoid at the valve is defective, with a small chance the wire has a short.

Many designs of them can be replaced (leaving the rest of the valve in place).

Comment: Awesome, i'll try that. I had all the valves (including solenoids) replaced last year so i'm surprised this is happening, but it may just be faster to replace the whole thing and move on.

Answer (score 0):

The sprinkler solenoid on station 6 is defective.  Replace the whole valve or if possible, just the solenoid.