# Sprinkler valve won't turn on by automatic timer

Tags: sprinkler-system, timer

Earlier this year, [I asked a question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/221698/sprinkler-valve-not-turning-on-by-automatic-timer/221738#221738) about why my station #6 wasn't turning on by the automatic timer. The advice was to get a new solenoid. I did that and it fixed the problem immediately.

My stations in the front are 6-8. My timer box has room for #9, which is currently unused.

I noticed recently that #7 isn't turning on by the timer. Thinking I was smart, I just headed to the hardware store and bought 2 new solenoids, because I figured I'd just replace #8 as well.

I replaced #7 and #8, but #7 still doesn't turn on by the timer (it does manually).

I also tried moving 7/8 up to 8/9. That didn't fix the issue either.

Anything else I should be looking at?

Comment: what else is there?

Comment: Check the wiring between the timer and #7.

Comment: In the past when there was a wiring issue the timer would report “err”. The timer isn’t reporting or showing anything abnormal when station 7 runs. Those sprinklers just don’t come on.

Comment: Do you know how solenoids work? Can you tell if electricity is arriving at the timer?

Answer (score 1):

There was a faulty connection in the line, unrelated to the solenoid, and to the previous problem I had with station 6.

My backyard timer wires go to 1 valve in my backyard, whose only purpose is to connect with another line that runs to the front yard. I have no idea why it's done like this, and why one line couldn't be run.

The connections between the two sets of wires looked tight, but the caps were off and the metal looked corroded. Perhaps they weren't conducting properly.

I made fresh cuts, reconnected, and everything worked perfectly.